# FIreStore on New Swift Project - FIRAuth getUID implementation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to get FireStore to work on Swift, but running into "FIRAuth getUID implementation wasn't set."  and I cannot get to my data.  I started with a Test app...   completely new Firestore project. New iOS project in Swift.  New Everything.  I just want to read some data.  THis is what I have so far...

xCode Version 9.3 (9E145)
FireStore rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

## AppDeligate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
 [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

## ViewController.swift

```
  import UIKit
  import Firebase
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          let db = Firestore.firestore()
              //  this gives
              // [Firebase/Core][I-COR000025] FIRAuth getUID implementation wasn't set.
              // and I cant read data after ward.
      }
```

NOTE: Add Firebase to your iOS APP.
Step 5...Run your app to verify installation
check_circle Congratulations, you've successfully added Firebase to your app!
So I know the app is connecting properly.

```
===========================
```

So I goto the FireStore docs at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

I add this code to ViewCOntroller.swift .

import UIKit
import Firebase
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
    //  this gives
    // [Firebase/Core][I-COR000025] FIRAuth getUID implementation 
        wasn't set.
    // and I cant read data after ward.

// Add a new document with a generated ID
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = db.collection("users").addDocument(data: [
    "first": "Ada",
    "last": "Lovelace",
    "born": 1815
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
    }
}
```

}

And I get this error...

```
2018-04-30 09:17:34.410768-0400 t5[32887:825090] 4.10.0 - 
[Firebase/Core][I-COR000025] FIRAuth getUID implementation wasn't 
set.
2018-04-30 09:17:34.625631-0400 t5[32887:825100] TIC Read Status 
[1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-04-30 09:17:34.625748-0400 t5[32887:825100] TIC Read Status 
[1:0x0]: 1:57
==============================================
Error adding document: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 
"Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={io.grpc.HeadersKey={
    "alt-svc" = "hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; 
quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; 
quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"43,42,41,39,35\"";
    "content-disposition" = attachment;
    date = "Mon, 30 Apr 2018 13:17:35 GMT";
    }, NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions., 
    io.grpc.TrailersKey={
        "content-disposition" = attachment;
}}
```

`=========================================`
My suspicion is that there is an Auth Issue, but I have my rules set to wide open.  I followed instruction perfectly.  I get the sence that I have to have some sort of Auth certificate.
That said, ultimately, all I want to do is read data from this site.
So, any thoughts out there what I am doing wrong?

`==============================================`

## I added more Post data and Read Data . and still getting...

```
`===============================
```

=====btn READDATA       =======
Error getting documents: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=13 "An internal error occurred." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error occurred.}

## 2018-04-30 12:01:00.004048-0400 t6[342:28839] Status bar could not find cached time string image. Rendering in-process.

=====btn POSTDATA       =======
Error adding document: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={io.grpc.HeadersKey={
    "alt-svc" = "hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"43,42,41,39,35\"";
    "content-disposition" = attachment;
    date = "Mon, 30 Apr 2018 16:01:01 GMT";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions., io.grpc.TrailersKey={
    "content-disposition" = attachment;
}}`

Comment: messing with this more... I am getting...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.  My Cocoa Pods needed updating.  Actually I did a completely new install of Cocoapds, but I recommend doing a pod update if you have this issue.  Simple as that.
yes it was a stupid mistake, but I would like to thank the poster that down gradded me.